# Index and alpha strategies research analyst

Tags: research, index

Just found some job offer:
[Index and alpha strategies research analyst](http://www.simplyhired.co.uk/job/xyw5rs4dld)

However it seems that the offer is already closed. The thing is I would like to know what are these alpha/index strategies. Can someone give brief description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a very broad statement that just means that you would research and document the performance of fixed income strategies of two kinds: those that simply follow an index (passive strategies) or those that attempt to outperform passive indexes by following an active (but systematic) approach. An example of the latter might be momentum strategies.

So in essence it hardly says anything at all ;)

Comment: Ok, I get what you mean. I understand that alpha are those outperforming strategies.